# Changing complete project orientation in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

when user is change orientation of device landscape to Portrait mode my app  complete orientation should be change  how can i change complete app orientation not for particular view i need to change total app

Answer (score 0):

Go to Target --> Supported Device orientation --> select the orientation required

Edit

Try this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    // return YES;
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Apple.developer : The accelerometers in iOS–based devices make it possible to determine the current orientation of the device. By default, an app supports both portrait and landscape orientations. When the orientation of an iOS–based device changes, the system sends out a **UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification** notification to let any interested parties know that the change occurred. By default, the UIKit framework listens for this notification and uses it to update your interface orientation automatically. This means that, with only a few exceptions, you should not need to handle this notification at all.

Implementing the supportedInterfaceOrientations method

```
 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations

    {    
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;    
    }
```

See more details  [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)